# Asynchronous task pending in custom action filter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I need your help! I've been a while around this and I haven't been able to figure it out. Let's suppose we have the following controller:

```
class NotifierController : MyBaseController {
    ... 
    [HttpGet]
    [CanNotifyUser]
    public async Task<ActionResult> NotifyUser(string id)
    {
        return View(await DataBase.Users.FindAsync(id));
    }
    // More actions decorated with the CanNotifyUserAttribute attribute
}
```

`DataBase` is a property defined in `MyBaseController` like:

```
static ApplicationDbContext _appDbContext;
public ApplicationDbContext DataBase 
{ 
    get { return _appDbContext ?? (_appDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext()); } 
}
```

`ApplicationDbContext` inherits from `IdentityDbContext<MyUser>` where `MyUser` inherits from `IdentityUser`. So, my problem (I think) comes to the custom action filter `CanNotifyUserAttribute`, whose `OnActionExecuting` override is defined as (removing all checks to reduce as much as possible):

```
public override async void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    NotifierController controller = filterContext.Controller as NotifierController;
    Boss boss = await controller.DataBase.Bosses.FindAsync(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId());
    object id = filterContext.ActionParameters["id"];
    User user = await controller.DataBase.Users.FindAsync(id.ToString());
    if (user.Department.Id != boss.Department.Id)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
            new RouteValueDictionary(
                new
                {
                    action = "Login",
                    controller = "Account",
                    returnUrl = controller.Url.Action("NotifyUser", new { id = id })
                }));
    }
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

The idea with this attribute is to verify that a boss sends notifications to the users of his department only. Now comes the strange part, this only happens the first time I try to send a notification to an user (no matter whether it's of the same department or not), the error thronw is:

> [InvalidOperationException: An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.]

If I try (after the error) the same request (i.e., notify the user) it works as expexted either redirecting or sending the notification.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28805796/asp-net-controller-an-asynchronous-module-or-handler-completed-while-an-asynchr) I might be finishing the request (If I understood well) before an asynchronous task is finished, but all the tasks I've been using are all `await`ed so I don't know where this error may come from. Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you implemented [Fire and forget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803012/fire-and-forget-with-async-vs-old-async-delegate) pattern the behavior is expected... Now what do you actually expect this code would do?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov hmmm So should I do `task.Wait()` in the `NotifyUser` action? I tried it in the attribute with no luck.

Comment: Not going to work. When it deadlocks make sure to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock. Feels like you expect action filters to support asynchronous operations and it simply not the case (same for views)... I don't think you get anywhere without significant redesign as only top level actions in ASP.Net MVC supporting async.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Don't know how there's dead lock happening 'cause it's only one request and isn't `IdentityDbContext` thread safe?

Comment: Sorry, my comment was about attempts to fix `OnActionExecuting` - there is nothing wrong with `NotifyUser` action.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov So should I implement this logic away from attributes?

Comment: If you need asynchronous operations and you care about result of the operation - yes. Otherwise fire-an-forget may work (I think you need to do some equivalent of WebForms' RegisterAsyncTask to get it working), but I'd not go that route.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thank you very much for your time. Never occurred to me to search for support for asynchronous operations on action filters.

Comment: Yeah, the fundamental problem is that this version of ASP.NET/MVC is tragically flawed when it comes to async operations in action filters.  ASP.NET/WebApi is *way* better in this regard, but doesn't really help you.

Comment: This is also fixed in ASP.NET Core. But ASP.NET MVC Classic does not support async filters or async child actions. :/

Comment: Also see my [article on async ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx) where I note this error is usually due to `async void` (i.e., `async void OnActionExecuting`), and also have a section on "Current State of Async Support".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to enforce async behaviour on your filter by turning `OnActionExecuting` into an `async void`. `asnyc void` methods should only be used in the context of asynchronous event handlers due to their special error-handling semantics and the "inability" of the calling process to wait for the tasks executed inside your (filter-)method's body (for further reading, consider [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) great article by Stephen Cleary).

Therefore, with ASP.NET Core, consider using the [IAsyncActionFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.iasyncactionfilter?view=aspnetcore-2.1) interface instead.

> Filters support both synchronous and asynchronous implementations through different interface definitions. [...] Asynchronous filters define a single OnStageExecutionAsync method. This method takes a FilterTypeExecutionDelegate delegate which executes the filter's pipeline stage.
>   ([Filters in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#implementation))

So instead of...

```
public override async void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
```

...use:

```
public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
```

For further instructions on how to use this see: [Async OnActionExecuting in ASP.NET Core's ActionFilterAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43979889/async-onactionexecuting-in-asp-net-cores-actionfilterattribute)