# I can't pass an object from the filter to the controller when my filter method is async. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following model:

Customer:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
   ... some props
}
```

And the following repository-pattern method:

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, string includeProperties = "")
{
    IQueryable<T> query = _dbset; 

    foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
        (new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        query = query.Include(includeProperty);
    }

    return  await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(where);
}
```

I have the following filter:

```
public class IncludeCustomerToHttpContext : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override async void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var customerRepository = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ICustomerRepository>();

        var authHeader = context.HttpContext.Request?.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();

        if (!Int32.TryParse(authHeader, out int clientId))
        {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
        }

        var customer = await customerRepository.GetAsync(x => x.CustomerId == clientId, typeof(Application).Name);

        if (customer == null)
        {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
        }

        context.ActionArguments["Customer"] = customer;
    }
}
```

And the following action in the controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromBody] CustomerChangeViewModel viewModel, Customer customer)
{
    ...
}
```

If `OnActionExecuting` is async I have empty (default) `customer` object. To fix it I must remove  `async` from `OnActionExecuting` and make the method as sync. But it's not good. Because it means that I'm forced to make `GetAsync` synchronous. Why it's happening? What is wrong? How to fix it?

### Update

Thank you for comments! Now i have the following filter

```
public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
    var customerRepository = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ICustomerRepository>();

    var authHeader = context.HttpContext.Request?.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();

    if (!Int32.TryParse(authHeader, out int clientId))
    {
        context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
    }

    var customer = await customerRepository.GetAsync(x => x.CustomerId == clientId, typeof(Application).Name);

    if (customer == null)
    {
        context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
    }

    context.ActionArguments["Customer"] = customer;

    await next(); 
}
```

But after running I have the following exception:

> "IncludeCustomerToHttpContext" is not an attribute

I forgot something?

Comment: You may want to have a look at the following https://stackoverflow.com/a/43979995/5233410

Comment: `async void` is the problem here. Since you're not returning a `Task`, the ASP.NET Core MVC pipeline doesn't wait for your asynchronous call to complete. Override `OnActionExecutionAsync`, as shown in the answer linked by @Nkosi.

Comment: Thank you for comments, could you check update of the question?

Comment: Done) Just forgot to inherit `Attribute`) Thank you for comments)